# Ember hasMany relationships fetching

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

In my application, I have a model, lets say `Tree` and `Leaf`.

```
App.Tree = DS.Model.extend
  leaves: DS.hasMany 'leaf'

App.Leaf = DS.Model.extend
  dead: DS.attr 'boolean'
  tree: DS.belongsTo 'tree'
```

I want to be able to have only dead `leaves` in the tree, like `deadLeaves: DS.hasMany 'leaf'`. Since I want to just pull `Trees` with dead `Leaves` from server in JSON response and pull all the leaves for specific tree only when needed.

Is this possible, other than creating a model `App.DeadLeaf = DS.Leaf.extend()` and specifying relation like this `deadLeaves: DS.hasMany 'deadLeaf'`?

Or is it possible to setup parameters for association when it's pulled from server, like `tree.get('leaves', dead: true') ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you only ever using dead leaves on you client? Do you need your client to know about the live leaves?

Comment: I want to show a list of `Trees` with additional information about their `dead leaves`. And if someone clicks on the specific `Tree`, it shows summary about all leaves, therefore creating asynchronous request for all leaves. But for all `Trees`, I need to embed only dead leaves in the JSON response, since embedding of all leaves is not possible due to huge JSON response.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the issue... Can your tree have `leaves` which is all of them but defined `async` and `deadleaves` which are embedded?